listofitems delimiter no longer recognized after passing through \readlist
I'm passing a list of arguments through various functions in order to ultimately produce an itemized list.
The list of arguments is passed on in the form of a single string that contains various delimiters, which are being picked apart by calling \readlist from the listofitems package.
However, for some reason the delimiter within the arguments-string seems to no longer being recognized after passing through my sequence of macro calls. The following is the smallest example I could produce:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%=====================================================================[ macros ]

% function producing an itemized list
\newcommand{\modelAction}[1]{
    itemizing using "#1":
    
    \setsepchar{delimeter}
    \readlist*\actionConditionsList{#1}
    
    \begin{itemize}
    \foreachitem \actionCondition \in \actionConditionsList{
        \item \actionCondition \\
    }
    \end{itemize}
}

% function to pass on the argument both raw and "filtered" through \readlist
\newcommand{\dataCardSpecialActions}[1]{
    \setsepchar{::}
    \readlist*\actionArgs{#1}

    \modelAction{\actionArgs[1]}    % not working
    
    \modelAction{#1}                % working
}

%===================================================================[ document ]

\begin{document}

\dataCardSpecialActions{
    aaa
    delimeter
    bbb
}

\end{document}

In the code, \dataCardSpecialActions ends up calling the macro \modelAction with seemingly(?) the same input, but two different outcomes: When passing on the argument after a \readlist call, the delimeter seems to no longer being recognized.

As always, any help would be appreciated!

You need to expand the argument in order for the list parser to see the delimiters. One way to do this is using \ExpandArgs as follows.
In order to get the same output, you also need to get rid of additional spaces. If you use \NewDocumentCommand etc., you can use \TrimSpaces. Alternatively, you can be careful not to introduce them in the first place, as shown below.
Do not break lines in TeX using \\ as it causes bad boxes, as your example shows. If you want a line break, use a paragraph break and zap the indentation if necessary.
I've also corrected the quotation marks ;).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
% function producing an itemized list
\newcommand{\modelAction}[1]{%
  itemizing using ``#1'':

  \setsepchar{delimeter}%
  \readlist*\actionConditionsList{#1}%
  \begin{itemize}
    \foreachitem \actionCondition \in \actionConditionsList{%
      \item \actionCondition \par\noindent % avoid bad boxes
      }%
  \end{itemize}
}
% function to pass on the argument both raw and "filtered" through \readlist
\newcommand{\dataCardSpecialActions}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{::}%
  \readlist*\actionArgs{#1}%
  \ExpandArgs {e} \modelAction{\actionArgs[1]}% working
  \modelAction{#1}%                % working
}


\begin{document}

\dataCardSpecialActions{%
  aaa
  delimeter
  bbb%
}

\end{document}


Thank you! Especially for pointing out all the other inconsistencies as well! This answer does resolve the issue as posted.
Could you maybe expand (heh) on \ExpandArgs{e}? I tried looking it up, but found very little, especially on the e parameter.
I also tried rolling back my example towards the original code, and it quickly broke again. I added the roll-back to the original question, if that's okay?

@Fabian \ExpandArgs{} is relatively  new. it saves doing things with long strings of \expandafters interspersed with \noexpand. \ExpandArgs {e} \mycommand {myarg} expands myarg before \mycommand sees it. I'll try to look at your edited question later, but please change it to a followup if you need a faster response as somebody else can help you that way. (Just add a link to this question if you do.)

Ah cool, thank you! This might already be enough to answer my follow-up question; if not, I shall post it as a new question!

@Fabian ah, OK. in that case, maybe change this question back so this one answers it :-) and ask a new one if and when.

Ah yes, of course, done!
